# Коментарии на сайте в плане usability

Tags: php, mysql

Всем доброго дня.

Сайт, страница, комментарии на странице. Комментарии редактировать нельзя. Отсюда вопрос, как хранить эти комментарии? Каждый в отдельной ячейке таблицы (и добавлять записи) или все сваливать в ячейку формата "text" (и обновлять ее)? Имеется в плане, что быстрее, т.е. более usability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В отдельной ячейке, так быстрее, так как не надо парсить.

Плюс - имейте в виду, если сегодня редактировать не нужно, это не означает, что и завтра редактировать будет не нужно.